# A problem with index notation. Related variational calculus.

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors

i was reading a paper and i find something that i don't understand.

This is the paper "An action principle for action-dependent Lagrangians: Toward an action principle to non-conservative systems".

In the theorem II.1  the author writes. Let $\partial_{\mu}L=\gamma_{\mu}$ be a gradient $\gamma_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}f(x^{v})$ (1). The indexes in the left hand  side of the equation (1) are correct?

Can you give a place to read about this or one example?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to do *at least* one of the following to make this an answerable question: (1) give a *full citation* to the paper, including authors, publication date, and journal - preferably, also give a link to an online version if possible (and also preferably, one not behind a paywall). (2) Give sufficient context to the equation you are asking about for us to figure out what exactly $L, f$, and $x^\nu$ mean.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: 1)This is the [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08308.pdf) paper. The principal author is Matheus J. Lazo.

2) In the paper they trie to modified the action principle, in order to obtain the equations of motion of a particle under dissipative forces. $L$ represents the Lagrangian function, $x^{\nu}$ are the coordinates of a vector defined in domain $\Omega \in R$ and $f$ is a scalar field.

Comment: $f$ is a function of all the $x^\nu$. I.e., of the point in space. The author is just using $x^\nu$ as a shorthand for $(x^1, x^2, \dots, x^d)$. It is a poor notation, in my opinion, so I cannot blame you for finding it confusing. The right-hand size does not depend on $\nu$ as an index at all. This is a recurring choice: whenever you see $g(x^\iota)$ in this paper, for any map $g$ and index $\iota$, the author means $x^\iota := (x^1, \dots, x^d)$

Comment: +1 for provoking the glimpse